# Wordpress - Remove duplicate active class form menu

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

In my Wordpress 4.6/Bootstrap 2.2.1 menu I have added a menu item, that just is a page/blog made up of blog posts marked with a certain category. This works almost as intended, except from that when this category page is active both this menu item and the blog menu item is getting the `class="active"` assigned to the `<li>`.

ex.

[about] [**blog**] [**blog-category-page**] [contact]

How can I use jQuery to disable the active class for my blog `<li>` if the blog-category-page is selected?

Comment: please add code or link for referance.

Comment: $("#menuitem li").removeClass(theClass) will remove the said class